# PDOException not triggering / possible scope related?

Tags: php, pdo

In anticipation of mysql_query being deprecated PHP 5.5.0, I have been working on a class to handle all my DB queries :

```
class DataBaseClass {

    //.....some other function and variables declared here....

    function GetConnection() {
        try {
          $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
          $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }

         return $this->conn;
     }

     function Query($str_sql, $arr_parameters = array()) {
         try {
            $this->str_mysql_error = $this->int_num_rows = $this->int_num_affected_rows = $this->int_mysql_insert_id =  '';

            if (count($arr_parameters) > 0) {
                $obj_result = $this->conn->prepare($str_sql);
                $obj_result->execute($arr_parameters);
            } else {
                $obj_result = $this->conn->query($str_sql);
            }


         }

         catch(PDOException $e) { 
             $this->str_mysql_error = $e->getMessage() . $str_sql;

          }
     }
}
```

Then I have another class to create new user:

```
class AddNewUser {
    //.....some other function and variables declared here....

    function InsertUser() {
          $str_sql = "INSERT INTO  (uname, name, email, pass, user_regdate, theme)       VALUES )";
           $_SESSION['db_connection']->Query($str_sql, '');         

     }
}
```

Now on my main user creation page I have :

```
$_SESSION['db_connection'] = new DataBaseClass; 
//Reason I used $_SESSION to store my DB object, is so that it can be accessible everywhere. 
//Did not want to use "global" everywhere. Not sure if this is he best way???

$cls_new_user = new AddNewUser ();
$cls_new_user->InsertUser(); //Does not raise PDOExecption although SQL cleary wrong inside this method
if ( $_SESSION['db_connection']->str_mysql_error) {
    //show error in error div
}


$str_sql = "SELECT some wrong SQL statment";
$_SESSION['db_connection']->Query($str_sql); // This does raise PDOExecption

if ( $_SESSION['db_connection']->str_mysql_error) {
    //show error in error div
}
```

I'm not sure why the DB class function "Query" would not raise an exception on clearly wrong SQL when called from another class. But same function called from main page code (not inside function / class) raises and exception error.

Also, the  "InsertUser" function does not execute / insert anything into DB even if SQL correct.

Could it be scope related, or the fact that I'm trying to enforce global scope of my DB object by putting it in $_SESSION ??

Am I going about this the wrong way? Reason for going class route to encapsulate all my DB calls was to avoid any deprecation issues in future -  only having to update class.

Comment: How do you know that exception weren't raised?

Comment: I'm sure it does raise an exception, but you catch it - and you don't check `$this->str_mysql_error` after the fact.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the code where i check the var $this->str_mysql_error .

I have added it now. 

the first if statement $_SESSION['db_connection']->str_mysql_error is empty.

second one has error and triggers the display of my error div

Comment: Hmm - did you log/debug to check if the catch block is reached and the str_mysql_error variable is empty for other reasons?

Comment: yes, i also put a `print "PDO error";` in the catch block, but if never prints out when called from the class AddNewUser->InsertUser();

When the wrong SQL statment in the main page calls the same funtion "Query" catch block is reached, "PDO error" shows, and my error div is shown

Comment: OK, after two days of pulling my hair out, I found the problem. 

`AddNewUser->InsertUser();` method, I call the query function like this :

`$_SESSION['db_connection']->Query($str_sql, '');`

Assuming that the second parameter being empty string will then cause the method parameter to default to an empty array. As they say assumption is the mother of all....

But because I leave out the second parameter in my main page call , it does default to to empty array.

only when i put an `if` around the `$obj_result->execute($arr_parameters)` did i realise that it's not triggering the catch block

Comment: What i don't get though is why my 

`if (count($arr_parameters) > 0) {`

did not then execute `$obj_result = $this->conn->query($str_sql);` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make your function this way.

```
 function Query($str_sql, $arr_parameters = array()) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($str_sql);
        $stmt->execute($arr_parameters);
 }
```

I am pretty sure that exception would be thrown

The only issue can be with *catching* exceptions, not throwing. And it could be caused by Namespace, not scope. To be certain, you can always prepend all PDO calls with a slash:

```
\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
\PDOException
```

etc.